# Purchase header for demo site

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a website that I am building for a demo-purchase site using wordpress. On the top it has a header bar. This header has the option to click "Remove Frame" and it disappears. I used JQuery create this effect. My problem is that once I make the header disappear, and then I click on a different link for the website the header comes back. How can I make it stay disappeared once you click the "Remove Frame" option? Here is a link to the site: http://www.demo.doneforbodyshops.com/

Comment: Can you post the relevant code here?

Comment: Use a cookie to store the fact that the user has dismissed the frame.

Answer (score 0):

Every new page loaded that contains the header will reload the header, this is normal. You need a **session cookie** to store the changes. By the way, it would be more sensible to reload the header on every new page if there is no way to re-display it.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the header bar by using:

```
$("#div1").remove()
```

which will remove the header bar from the DOM

Comment: Thank you mbadeveloper, this was definitely easier than the way I had coded it, but it still doesn't remove the header once and for all after clicking  "Remove Frame". Unless I am placing it in the wrong section, I put it in between the <head></head> tags.